# bash for loop all directories and execute command inside

Tags: bash, shell, unix, for-loop

I am already doing a `for loop` inside all my directories starting with **abcd** and it is working. But when I have other files or stuff in the root directory, it crashes after the first loop.

```
dir_1="./some/path1"
dir_2="./some/path2"
dir_3="./some/path3"

for f in ./abcd*;
    do      
        [ -d $f ] && cd "$f" && echo I am inside $f

        find $dir_1 -name something*.txt -exec cp {} $dir_3 \;
        find $dir_2 -name another*.txt -exec cp {} $dir_3 \;

        cd "$dir_3"
        # do some other stuff here
        cd ../../..     
    done;
```

could somebody help me repair it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The glob itself can be restricted to directories, at which point you can simply skip to the next iteration if the `cd` fails.

```
for f in ./abcd*/;
do      
    pushd "$f" || continue

    find "$dir_1" -name something*.txt -exec cp {} "$dir_3" \;
    find "$dir_2" -name another*.txt -exec cp {} "$dir_3" \;

    pushd "$dir_3"
    # do some other stuff here
    popd
    popd
done
```

`pushd` and `popd` make changing directories and changing back simpler. (Since you don't do anything between the two `popd`s, you can replace the second `pushd` with a simple `cd` and drop the corresonding `popd`.)